# jQuery/Javascript Plugin best practice

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip, tiptip

I'm not particular familiar with using jQuery/Javascript so I don't know what the best way to do what I'm asking, it works but I don't know how efficient it is.

Basically I have a plugin called [TipTip](http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/tiptip-jquery-plugin) to create tooltips. It either takes the info from the "title" attribute of what you want the tip to appear over or you can use an option in the script to include HTML, like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$(".someClass").tipTip({content:"<strong>What you want in the tooltip</strong>"; })             
});
</script>
```

I want to generate a lot of *different* tooltips on my page but they all fit a similar style and really only need a changeable variable (they are an achievement progress bar so I only need to pass a single value for the % progress).

So is it alright to simply have a lot of script tags and duplicate the code above or can I pass a variable into it somehow and only keep the one piece of tooltip code at the top?

Or is this a question for suited to the devs of TipTip? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming HTML5 is ok to use in this scenario, I'd reccommend using the [html data attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) to store your element specific tooltips... and then using it to populate the tiptip plugin...

```
$(function(){
    $('.toolTipClass').each(function() {
        var element = $(this);
        element.tipTip({
            content: "<strong>"+element.data("toolTip")+"</strong>"
    });
});
```

Now just add the HTML5 attribute like so

```
<div class="toolTipClass" data-toolTip="This is the tool Tip">Div Content</div>
```

Comment: Use `.data` instead of a `.attr` -.-

Comment: Even easier, element.data('toolTip') will work with jQuery 1.6+. data() will fetch any data- attribute, too.

Comment: Ah, possibly because you forgot to close one of the functions, the Tip is coming up now but I'm getting "null" though it has the strong effect.

Comment: Hmm, changing it back to attr("data-toolTip") fixed it. Is there something wrong with using .data or is it meant to be slightly different?

Comment: confirm that you're using jquery 1.6+ if not, you'll have to use `.attr()`

Comment: Using the latest `http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js` Tried using a specific version above 1.6 just in case as well. Slight correction, it's coming up `undefined` as opposed to `null`

Comment: interesting, if `attr()` works I'd just go with that, `.data()` is needed when you need strict typing of your data, since you're just after a string, `attr()` is fine.

Comment: Fair enough, I thought it should be okay but it was worth checking. Cheers for all the help. =)